# animated shadow effect with fluctuating shadow

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-float

How to create continuous changing shadow of text that fluctuates automatically on users side like CSS effect that is animated text with continuous changing shadow width.

I know how to add CSS shadow but how to make it fluctuating?

```css
#shadow {
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div id=shadow>shadow effect how to fluctuate it</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the effect you're after? It's hard to tell from your description. An image or animated gif will do, or a link to some example website.

Comment: What do you mean by *fluctuating*

Comment: i meant by fluctuating  is continious changing width of  shadow once increasing then decresing  @Mr.Alien

Comment: sir i could not find the sample but i an trying to create an animated text whose shadow keeps on changing @RacilHilan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you mean by fluctuation here, but if you want to change the blur radius of your `text-shadow`, you can use `animation` here...

I am using `@keyframes` and animating the `X` `Y` and blur of your `text-shadow`. If you want, you can animate a particular axis or the blur radius only by changing the value `8px` to something else.

```css
#shadow {
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa;
  animation: animate-shadow 1s ease-in infinite;
}

@keyframes animate-shadow {
  50% {
    text-shadow: 8px 8px 8px #aaa;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id=shadow>shadow effect how to fluctuate it</div>
```

Comment: sir i was trying to do something like this only

Comment: @AnuragBatra Great :) you can also change the `color` or something similar, just keep on adding properties to your `@keyframes`

Answer (score 2):

Use key-frames and blur your text shadow

```
#shadow {
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes mymove {
  50% {text-shadow: 10px 20px 30px #aaa;}
}

<div id=shadow>shadow effect how to fluctuate it</div>
```